# Javascript compare 2 arrays and create a new array based on the order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays mentioned below. using this i need to create a new array based on the values in `dimentionFilterKeyOrder` which need to compare with `dimentionFilterKeys` values. Also the items which are not matching in the `dimentionFilterKeys` need to be list in the last of the new array.

Note: new array Order should be similar to `dimentionFilterKeyOrder`.

```
dimentionFilterKeyOrder= ["21","22","23","14","10312","81","10315","10314"];

dimentionFilterKeys = [
  {"filterKey": "81"},
  {"filterKey": "82"},
  {"filterKey": "10312"},
  {"filterKey": "10313"},
  {"filterKey": "10315"},
  {"filterKey": "10314"},
  {"filterKey": "20"},
  {"filterKey": "21"},
  {"filterKey": "22"},
  {"filterKey": "23"},
  {"filterKey": "24"},
  {"filterKey": "14"}
]
```

OutPut looking for similar to below.

```
newArryaOutPut = [
  {"filterKey": "21"},
  {"filterKey": "22"},
  {"filterKey": "23"},
  {"filterKey": "14"},
  {"filterKey": "10312"},
  {"filterKey": "81"},
  {"filterKey": "10315"},
  {"filterKey": "10314"},
  {"filterKey": "82"},
  {"filterKey": "10313"},
  {"filterKey": "20"},
  {"filterKey": "24"}
]
```

Comment: Could you post the expected result with the given arrays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, order of keys non existing in order array can't  be predicted tho.

```
var compareFunc = function(a, b) {
    let indexA = dimentionFilterKeyOrder.indexOf(a['filterKey']);
  let indexB = dimentionFilterKeyOrder.indexOf(b['filterKey']);
  if(indexA==-1)
    return 1;
  if(indexB==-1)
    return -1;
  return indexA-indexB;
}

var sorted = dimentionFilterKeys.sort(compareFunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort method. Using the index of `filterKey`, you can sort your array of object.

NOTE: The value which are not in the `dimentionFilterKeyOrder` will move to the end will not be sorted. `Array#sort()` do in-place sorting, in case you want your original array to be un-modified, you can use `array#slice()` and then sort it.

```js
const dimentionFilterKeyOrder= ["21","22","23","14","10312","81","10315","10314"],
      dimentionFilterKeys = [{"filterKey":"81"},{"filterKey":"82"},{"filterKey":"10312"},{"filterKey":"10313"},{"filterKey":"10315"},{"filterKey":"10314"},{"filterKey":"20"},{"filterKey":"21"},{"filterKey":"22"},{"filterKey":"23"},{"filterKey":"24"},{"filterKey":"14"}];

dimentionFilterKeys.sort((a,b) => {
  let indexA = dimentionFilterKeyOrder.indexOf(a.filterKey),
      indexB = dimentionFilterKeyOrder.indexOf(b.filterKey);
  indexA = indexA == -1 ? Infinity : indexA + 1;
  indexB = indexB == -1 ? Infinity : indexB + 1;
  return indexA - indexB;
});

console.log(dimentionFilterKeys);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @NinaScholz What do I need to change to make it stable?

Comment: the original index makes it stable, but that does not work in the way, you are sorting directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and take the index for known positions and `Infinity` for sorting to the and by keeping the original order of the array.

```js
var order = ["21","22","23","14","10312","81","10315","10314"],
    array = [{ filterKey: "81" }, { filterKey: "82" }, { filterKey: "10312" }, { filterKey: "10313" }, { filterKey: "10315" }, { filterKey: "10314" }, { filterKey: "20" }, { filterKey: "21" }, { filterKey: "22" }, { filterKey: "23" }, { filterKey: "24" }, { filterKey: "14" }],
    result = array.map(function (o, i) {
        return { index: i, order: (order.indexOf(o.filterKey) + 1) || Infinity };
    })
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.order - b.order || a.index - b.index;
    })
    .map(function (o) {
        return array[o.index];
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```